# Como alterar o valor de um atributo dentro de uma `TD` usando jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```js
var saldo = 10;
$(".saldo").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-saldo]').html("10.00");//setando o valor da coluna
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-saldo]').data("saldo", "10.00");//setando o valor do atributo
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      <th scope="col">Marca</th>
      <th scope="col">Valor</th>
      <th><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Check</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td data-saldo="0.00">0.00</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary saldo">Check</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td data-saldo="0.00">0.00</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary saldo">Check</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td data-saldo="0.00">0.00</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary saldo">Check</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> e note que a `td` correspondente ao valor possui um atributo `data-saldo` vindo carregado com valor `0.00`, supondo que ao clicar no botão `check` ele mude o valor deste atributo para 10, como posso fazer, tentei da forma que está no `js` do `snippet`, mas não alterou.

Comment: O valor foi alterado pra 10 como você pediu

Comment: Entao mas se clicar com o botao direito do mouse para checar o valor não está alterado, eu preciso que altere o valor no atributo também.

Comment: Já tentou $(element).attr("data-saldo","10.00")?

Comment: Então, eu respondi e aqui deu certo

Comment: O `data` no JQuery não reflete as alterações como um atributo do html, apenas com JS puro isso acontece.  Também deve minimizar as pesquisas no DOM que faz, que no caso tem duas iguais seguidas desnecessariamente. Pode fazer isto quer encadeando (dependo dos métodos chamados) ou memorizando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foi basicamente o que eu cometei, com attr() deu certo

```js
var saldo = 10;
$(".saldo").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-saldo]').html("10.00");//setando o valor da coluna
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-saldo]').attr("data-saldo", "10.00");//setando o valor do atributo
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      <th scope="col">Marca</th>
      <th scope="col">Valor</th>
      <th><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Check</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td data-saldo="0.00">0.00</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary saldo">Check</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td data-saldo="0.00">0.00</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary saldo">Check</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td data-saldo="0.00">0.00</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary saldo">Check</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```